# Convert Bitmap to Bitmap[] array

Tags: java, android, bitmap

```
List<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
public Bitmap[] thumbs = { };
```

I fetch image from my method `fetchImage(String url)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < (url.size()); i++) {
   /* I fetch image with param String URL and return as Bitmap */
   Bitmap photo = fetchImage(url.get(i));
}
```

How to push `Bitmap photo` into `Bitmap[] thumbs` as array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as following:

```
List<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
public Bitmap[] thumbs = new Bitmap[url.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < (url.size()); i++) {
   /* I fetch image with param String URL and return as Bitmap */
   thumbs[i] = fetchImage(url.get(i));
}
```